# How to compare signal to zero in vhdl?

Tags: comparison, vhdl, comparator

I have signal:

```
signal sig: std_logic_vector(N - 1  downto 0);
```

Where N defined in generic, and can be from 16 to 1024.

In code i need to compare this to zero:

```
if unsigned(sig) = 0 then
  do somth
end if;
```

But how can I know which delay would be of such comparator?
My design work on 100 MHz, so I need to make some divider, which will skip some tackts to obtain result, something like that:

```
constant CHECK_TACKTS : natural := 100;
signal check : boolean;
signal wait_check_cntr: natural range 0 to CHECK_TACKTS;

-- states
when SOME_STATE=>
    check <= unsigned(sig) = 0;
    wait_check_cntr <= 0;
    state <= CHECK_ZERO 

when CHECK_ZERO =>    
    if wait_check_cntr = CHECK_TACKTS then
        if check then
            --do somth
        end if; 
    else
        wait_check_cntr <= wait_check_cntr + 1;
    end if;
```

But how can I calculate CHECK_TACKTS, if I know, thet counter period is 10 ns? If xilinx synthes tool build full compare tree on luts, seems like compare time can be proportional to log2(N), but what about lut time? Of course I can do research and measure timings from report on several points and than perform  regression, but may be there are simpiler way?

Comment: You could use a comparator that uses a carry-chain to speed up.

Comment: If you're using an FPGA, to get a 1024-bit comparator to work at 100 MHz, you will need to use some pipelining. Also, what does 'tackts' mean? I'm not sure what your 3rd code segment is supposed to do.

Comment: You don't need to know the delay, the synthesis tool will tell you if it can't meet timings. Then, you can modify your design so it does. On FPGAs, the timings through LUTs is constant, and less than the routing timings (from LUT to LUT). To compare 1024 bits to 0 on a Spartan-6 or better FPGA, your critical path is 4 LUTs. 4 LUTs is small and pass 100MHz hands down, but routing 1024 signals may be a problem. Did you try it? Did it fail timings?

Comment: I second the remark of Jonathan. When you code at the RTL level, you should make an hypothesis that the time to flow through the critical path is less than the target 1/frequency of your registers. Then you ask the synthesizer to check if this hypothesis is true...or not.

Comment: 2scary_jeff tackts means periods of main CLK signal(10 ns each) that I wait before capture slow signal. I thought, when I write "check <= unsigned(sig) = 0;" syntheser put logic, which have delay that are bigger than 10 ns, so then I wait 100 * 10 ns = 1us and only after that read "check" signal. I know that it is some kind of my re-invention of the wheel, but it works, only thing I want is to reduce 100 to some optimal value. Can you please tell in several words about pipelinig? What is it and how can it be applied in my case? Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanDrolet Actually the delay trough a LUT is not constant. LUTs can be used to fine tune wire delays to force flip flops into meta stability state and to produce a 'true' random signal, which can be used in a true random number generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to pipeline your comparaison operation on Xilinx is to let the tool do it for you. You need to activate the "register balancing" option and use syntax such as:

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
    check_0 <= unsigned(sig) = 0;
    check_1 <= check_0;
    check   <= check_1;
end if;
```

XST (or Vivado) will distribute the compare operation on three cycles (for that case).

If you prefer not to rely on the synthesis tool, you can manually divide the operation yourself:

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
    check_msb <= unsigned(sig'left downto sig'length/2) = 0;
    check_lsb <= unsigned(sig'length/2-1 downto 0) = 0;
    check     <= check_msb and check_lsb;
end if;
```

This may not be the optimal way to balance the comparaison, but the VHDL code is simple, easy to modify and to understand.